# How to add a button in a ASP.NET MVC and link a click event from C# code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a button on my ASP.NET page. I have experience with Windows forms and I know how to link a click event to a button, but in ASP.NET MVC this link is different.

How to make this link correctly so that when I click the button, the click event written in my c# source to be triggered?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't have "events" in the same way. WebForms does, but not MVC. In MVC, you can cause a button click to trigger a controller action method (either via a hyperlink or by submitting a form, or triggering an AJAX request which goes to the URL of the action). I suggest you study Microsoft's introductory ASP.NET MVC tutorial which will introduce you to the basic concepts and also the ways of doing standard tasks such as this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need create a tag in cshtml file as

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")">Click</a>
```

And create method to handle click in controller c# as

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    //C# code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it by passing parameters, first of all add the button in cshtml file

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new{ parameter = "value"})">Click here</a>
```

And finally in the controller create a method

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string parameter){
       //Your code here
}
```